# How do I check where Lot number of GS1 ends when scanning with Expo barcode scanner?

Tags: expo, barcode, barcode-scanner, gs1-datamatrix, gs1-ai-syntax

Since Lot number in GS1 standard starts with 10 and has length UP TO 20, and the end is determined with FNC1 symbol, which is invisible, I have no idea how to check wether it really ended or not

This case scenario would work if it was actually seperated by whitespace but not FNC1, any ideas?

```js
function getCode(code, pos, len){
    let str = ''
    for(pos; pos < len + pos; pos++){
        str+=code[pos]
        if(str[pos+1] === ' '){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The transmission protocol for all GS1-supported barcode symbologies is that FNC1 non-data characters serving as AI separators in the barcode message be transferred a Group Separator data characters (ASCII 29).

The leading FNC1 character in first position must also be indicated, e.g. via the modifier value of an AIM Symbology Identifier prefix or a similar proxy.

Any scanner that does not do this, or cannot be configured to do this, is seriously defective since it does not comply with the generic symbology standards.